# jQuery: hide everything in a container, except one node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a HTML container with some contents, including texts nodes and other tags:

```
<div id="container">
    A text outside any tag<br/>
    <input type="button" id="iii" value="xxx"/>
    Another text<br/>
    <a href="#">A link</a>
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery to hide everything in that container except the input tag.

```
// Hide all the node
$("#container").contents().hide();

// First try to hide texts
$("#container").contents().filter(":text").hide();
// Second try
$("#container").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).hide();

// Show the desired element
$("#container #iii").show();
```

The link "A link" is removed, but the texts before and after the input still remains.

What is the right way to hide a text that is a direct child of a DOM element?

You can [play with that example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7yuq8b6/2/)

Comment: I would add everything inside the container I want to hide inside sub-containers of one class and everything I don't want to hide inside sub-containers of another. Or, create two copies of the whole container, the second copy contains only the elements I don't want to hide and starts hidden, or forget about hide/show and just user jQuery to generate the contents of the container based on whatever conditions you wish.

Comment: whats the reason for you not to put text in any tag

Comment: The reason is I don't have control on the generation of this html. It's generated by a framework I am not authorized to modify

Comment: Are you authorised to modify the html through javascript? For example putting a span around nodes?

Comment: @PraxisAshelin yes it could be a solution

Comment: @Antwane See comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399264/jquery-hide-everything-in-a-container-except-one-node/33399708#comment54590282_33399264  _"I am not authorized to modify"_ ? Perhaps remove comment if `html` _can_ be modified ? If `html` text nodes can be modified , could set their `.nodeValue` to empty string `""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `.hide()` will not work on the textnodes, because a style (in this case `display:none;`) always needs to be applied to a tag. It can't be applied to a node itself.

However, you can manipulate the HTML with Javascript to manually add spans around these textnodes:

```
// Get all the nodes in the container and loop over them
var allNodes = document.getElementById("container").childNodes;
for (i = 0; i < allNodes.length; i++) {
    var item = allNodes[i];

    if(item.tagName){
        // It already has a proper tag, so just hide it with a class
        $(item).addClass("hidden");
    }else{
        // Add a span around it
        $(item).wrap("<span class='hidden'>");
    }
}

$("#container #iii").removeClass("hidden");
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7yuq8b6/12/)

Then if you want to unhide the div contents later, you can simply remove the class, and leave the spans there (they won't hurt anyone).

```
$("#container .hidden").removeClass("hidden");
```

Comment: If `html` can be modified , not necessary to create new elements , could set `#text` node `.nodeValue` to empty string `""`

Comment: @guest271314 I'm guessing there's a reason why he wants to hide them instead of remove them. He may need to unhide them again afterwards.

Comment: Yes. Could store `nodeValue` as variable , set `nodeValue` to saved variable when display again

Comment: @guest271314 Feel free to add it as your own answer. For now I believe my own answer with hiding them leans more closely to what OP requested.

Comment: Interesting answer, I will check if I can use it to build my own solution.

Comment: Based on your answer, I finally get that I wanted at start. Thank you very much (my solution at https://jsfiddle.net/h7yuq8b6/14/)

Answer (score 3):

> The reason is I don't have control on the generation of this html.
>   It's generated by a framework I am not authorized to modify

Try setting `#container` , `#container *:not(#iii)` `css` `color` property to `transparent`

```js
$("#container, #container *:not(#iii)").css("color", "transparent")
```

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    A text outside any tag<br/>
    <input type="button" id="iii" value="xxx"/>
    Another text<br/>
    <a href="#">A link</a>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h7yuq8b6/10/

---

> Are you authorised to modify the html through javascript?

---

> yes it could be a solution

Alternatively, if `html` *can* be modified , could utilize `.clone()` to store original element as jQuery object, including all `html` content within element. Use `.each()` to iterate child nodes of original element, if node has "style" property call `.hide()` on child node , else set `#text` node `.nodeValue` to empty string.

Could reset `html` to original using clone of original element

```js
// save orginal `html`
var clone = $("#container").clone(); 

$("#container").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3 || this.id !== "iii"
}).each(function() {
  if ("style" in this) {
    $(this).hide()
  } else {
    this.nodeValue = ""
  }
})
```

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    A text outside any tag<br/>
    <input type="button" id="iii" value="xxx"/>
    Another text<br/>
    <a href="#">A link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not confusing you. I posted my old answer because I was marked down. Please focus on the new answer. If you have access to adding css here it is the solution. Else, you can use JavaScript and add this css; find button's location and dimension modify the css according to location and dimension. Then add the css using jQuery. Note that I used pink and red just to show you what I am doing!

```js
$('#container :not(label)').hide();
```

```css
#container2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
#container2:before{
    content: '\0020';
    width: 142px;
    height: 17.5px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: pink;
}
#container2:after{
    content: '\0020';
    width: 315px;
    height: 17.5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 40px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This is my old answer -->
<div id="container2">
    <label>A text outside any tag</label><br/>
    <input type="button" id="iii" value="xxx"/>
    <label>Another text</label><br/>
    <a href="#">A link</a>
</div>


<!-- This is the new answer -->
<br/><br/>
<div id="container">
    A text outside any tag<br/>
    <input type="button" id="iii" value="xxx"/>
    Another text<br/>
    <a href="#">A link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: _"It's generated by a framework I am not authorized to modify"_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399264/jquery-hide-everything-in-a-container-except-one-node#comment54590282_33399264

Comment: Ok, what do you want to hide/show? I just modified, that only displays text not in tags!

Comment: @PraxisAshelin I modified to show how to show only text. So please remove your down vote and focus your attention to help. Thanks!

Comment: @Gacci He wants to hide the text, and only show the button.

Comment: @PraxisAshelin Alright, so I reposted my old answer plus another answer. Using your logic, and if the logic holds you should remove your down vote and give me a up one.

Comment: @Gacci A downvote isn't the end of the world. Just try to make well-formatted and correct answers, that's what this site is all about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93618/discussion-between-gacci-and-praxis-ashelin).